Colab stuck in an infinite loop while installing PyTorch-related packages
I'm trying to install several PyTorch-related packages in Colab, but the installation process gets stuck in an infinite loop and doesn't complete, even though it doesn't give any error messages. I'm uninstalling and reinstalling the packages, but the installation process doesn't finish. Below is the code I am using:
import torch

!pip uninstall torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-geometric torch-cluster --y!pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html --no-cache-dir!pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html!pip install torch-cluster -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-{torch.__version__}.html!pip install git+https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric.git

The process seems to go into a loop without completing. Could someone please explain why this might be happening and how to fix it?

Can you install them one at a time and find which package causes the problem ?
